# Android Intellij The device is not ready

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, adb, intellij-14

After installing new version of Windows and intellij again i get this error:

```
The device is not ready
```

my project build is `Gradle` and after remove `.gradle` from home folder and `Invalidate Cache and Restart` and try to change `Target Device to USB` or other options my problem don't resolve. how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After change Android SDK location on files, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ADB drivers for your device is either missing or not installed properly, Do a clean install of latest Android Studio from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html , if you are testing it on a physical device enable USB debugging in developer options, Developer Options is usually a hidden setting, you can enable it by tapping build number around 7 times in About Phone, If you want to test it on an Emulator create a new AVD and make sure that you have the images for the device installed from SDK manager. You need not remove any .gradle file or any other file, just import the project in Android Studio, it should work without any issue in the latest version of android studio. If you need further help you can reach out to me at my mail or skype. I can also help you out via teamviewer, if you need.